# Android: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, when i try to set image view programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-image

I have the below code, which sets some texts and loads images.

Code:

```
private void buidAndroidComponentsFromRandom(int localVarRandomChoice){

        switch(localVarRandomChoice){

            case 0:
                        /* American food */
                        titleForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
                        logoForRandom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        addressForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_text);
                        foodImageForRandom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.numberDays);
                        foodDescForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodDesc);
                        titleForRandom.setText("How about Subway?");
                        logoForRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.subway);
                        addressForRandom.setText("Coffman Union\n3rd Floor\nWest bank");
                        foodImageForRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.sandwish);
                        foodDescForRandom.setText("Fish Sandich\n$5");

            case 1:
                        /* Cafe */
                        titleForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
                        logoForRandom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        addressForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_text);
                        foodImageForRandom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.numberDays);
                        foodDescForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodDesc);
                        titleForRandom.setText("How about Caribou Cafe?");
                        logoForRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.cariboulogo);
                        addressForRandom.setText("Coffman Union\n3rd Floor\nWest bank");
                        foodImageForRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.cariboufood);
                        foodDescForRandom.setText("Fish Sandich\n$5");

            case 2:
                        /* Chinese */
                        titleForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
                        logoForRandom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        addressForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_text);
                        foodImageForRandom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.numberDays);
                        foodDescForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodDesc);
                        titleForRandom.setText("How about Panda Express?");
                        logoForRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.pandaexpresslogo);
                        addressForRandom.setText("Coffman Union\n3rd Floor\nWest bank");
                        foodImageForRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.pandaexpressfood);
                        foodDescForRandom.setText("Fish Sandich\n$5");

            case 3:
                        /* Italian */
                        titleForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
                        logoForRandom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        addressForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_text);
                        foodImageForRandom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.numberDays);
                        foodDescForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodDesc);
                        titleForRandom.setText("How about Topios?");
                        logoForRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.topiologo);
                        addressForRandom.setText("Coffman Union\n3rd Floor\nWest bank");
                        foodImageForRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.topiofood);
                        foodDescForRandom.setText("Fish Sandich\n$5");

            case 4:
                        /* Juice */
                        titleForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
                        logoForRandom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        addressForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_text);
                        foodImageForRandom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.numberDays);
                        foodDescForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodDesc);
                        titleForRandom.setText("How about Jamba Juice?");
                        logoForRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.jambajuicelogo);
                        addressForRandom.setText("Coffman Union\n3rd Floor\nWest bank");
                        foodImageForRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.jambajuicefood);
                        foodDescForRandom.setText("Fish Sandich\n$5");

            case 5:
                        /* Mexican */
                        titleForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
                        logoForRandom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        addressForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_text);
                        foodImageForRandom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.numberDays);
                        foodDescForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodDesc);
                        titleForRandom.setText("How about Baja Sol?");
                        logoForRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.bajasollogo);
                        addressForRandom.setText("Coffman Union\n3rd Floor\nWest bank");
                        foodImageForRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.bajasolfood);
                        foodDescForRandom.setText("Fish Sandich\n$5");

            case 6:
                        /* Vietnamese */
                        titleForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
                        logoForRandom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        addressForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_text);
                        foodImageForRandom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.numberDays);
                        foodDescForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodDesc);
                        titleForRandom.setText("How about Bun Mi?");
                        logoForRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.bunmilogo);
                        addressForRandom.setText("Coffman Union\n3rd Floor\nWest bank");
                        foodImageForRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.bunmifood);
                        foodDescForRandom.setText("Fish Sandich\n$5");

            default:
                        /* Display some shit, who cares!! */
                        titleForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
                        logoForRandom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        addressForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_text);
                        foodImageForRandom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.numberDays);
                        foodDescForRandom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foodDesc);
                        titleForRandom.setText("How about Topios?");
                        logoForRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.topiologo);
                        addressForRandom.setText("Coffman Union\n3rd Floor\nWest bank");
                        foodImageForRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.topiofood);
                        foodDescForRandom.setText("Fish Sandich\n$5");
        }

    }
```

When i run the code, i get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError error and the app crashes. Here is the stack trace of the error. Could anybody please help me?

```
11-23 13:14:01.479: D/dalvikvm(32489): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 255K, 11% free 14003K/15600K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
11-23 13:14:01.479: I/dalvikvm-heap(32489): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.788MB for 3047632-byte allocation
11-23 13:14:01.499: D/dalvikvm(32489): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 9% free 16975K/18580K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
11-23 13:14:01.739: D/dalvikvm(32489): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 20K, 9% free 16955K/18580K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
11-23 13:14:01.739: I/dalvikvm-heap(32489): Grow heap (frag case) to 22.933MB for 5419408-byte allocation
11-23 13:14:01.759: D/dalvikvm(32489): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 7% free 22248K/23876K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
11-23 13:14:01.894: D/dalvikvm(32489): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3350K, 21% free 19000K/23876K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
11-23 13:14:01.899: I/dalvikvm-heap(32489): Grow heap (frag case) to 39.906MB for 21123232-byte allocation
11-23 13:14:01.914: D/dalvikvm(32489): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 39628K/44508K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
11-23 13:14:01.914: D/AbsListView(32489): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
11-23 13:14:01.914: I/MotionRecognitionManager(32489):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0,  
11-23 13:14:01.919: D/AbsListView(32489): unregisterIRListener() is called 
11-23 13:14:02.134: D/dalvikvm(32489): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 112K, 12% free 39518K/44508K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
11-23 13:14:02.134: I/dalvikvm-heap(32489): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 37552400-byte allocation
11-23 13:14:02.154: D/dalvikvm(32489): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 12% free 39508K/44508K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
11-23 13:14:02.154: E/dalvikvm-heap(32489): Out of memory on a 37552400-byte allocation.
11-23 13:14:02.154: I/dalvikvm(32489): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
11-23 13:14:02.154: I/dalvikvm(32489):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41b69578 self=0x41b546d0
11-23 13:14:02.154: I/dalvikvm(32489):   | sysTid=32489 nice=-16 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075073020
11-23 13:14:02.154: I/dalvikvm(32489):   | state=R schedstat=( 1495795700 225718854 2622 ) utm=111 stm=38 core=0
11-23 13:14:02.154: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
11-23 13:14:02.159: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
11-23 13:14:02.159: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
11-23 13:14:02.159: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
11-23 13:14:02.159: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
11-23 13:14:02.159: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
11-23 13:14:02.164: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:646)
11-23 13:14:02.164: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:375)
11-23 13:14:02.164: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at com.example.foodu.CuisineRecommendation.buidAndroidComponentsFromRandom(CuisineRecommendation.java:108)
11-23 13:14:02.164: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at com.example.foodu.CuisineRecommendation.onCreateOptionsMenu(CuisineRecommendation.java:53)
11-23 13:14:02.164: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2578)
11-23 13:14:02.164: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:507)
11-23 13:14:02.164: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:934)
11-23 13:14:02.164: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:292)
11-23 13:14:02.169: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
11-23 13:14:02.169: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
11-23 13:14:02.169: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
11-23 13:14:02.169: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
11-23 13:14:02.169: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-23 13:14:02.169: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-23 13:14:02.169: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
11-23 13:14:02.169: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
11-23 13:14:02.169: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 13:14:02.169: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-23 13:14:02.169: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
11-23 13:14:02.169: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
11-23 13:14:02.169: I/dalvikvm(32489):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-23 13:14:02.169: D/skia(32489): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
11-23 13:14:02.174: D/AndroidRuntime(32489): Shutting down VM
11-23 13:14:02.174: W/dalvikvm(32489): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b68700)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:646)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:375)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at com.example.foodu.CuisineRecommendation.buidAndroidComponentsFromRandom(CuisineRecommendation.java:108)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at com.example.foodu.CuisineRecommendation.onCreateOptionsMenu(CuisineRecommendation.java:53)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2578)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:507)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:934)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:292)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
11-23 13:14:02.179: E/AndroidRuntime(32489):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: How big is the image?

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to allocate 37552400 bytes = 35.8MB. That is **much too large**, equivalent to about an 8MP photo. On many devices, that is more memory than your entire app has, let alone how much you can use for a single image.

Reduce the resolution of your image resource to something more reasonable.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But when i don't set the images programmatically, [just set the image in the layout], it works perfectly fine. Also the size of the images are not too big, it is in terms of kilobytes. Still wondering why this is happening

Comment: I am not sure actually. but you are missing break statements in cases.   Can it be a problem?? because program try to set image in each cases when this code runs...

Comment: @Var: "Also the size of the images are not too big, it is in terms of kilobytes" -- that is the *on disk* size. PNG and JPEG files are stored on disk in a compressed form. In memory, they will consume *much* more space than they do on disk. Moreover, the OS needs 35.8MB to load in your image, whether you like it or not. Receme's point is also valid, in that you are calling `setImageResource()` many times unnecessarily, resulting in that much more memory consumption.

Comment: @Receme, Great catch, it is the reason i guess. Let me try putting the break statement and run it again!

Comment: An image, unless you scale it, needs x times y times 4 bytes.